# How do I import RDBMS data to a specific hive database using sqoop import

Tags: mysql, database, import, hive, sqoop

I need to import external database from mysql into hive using sqoop. My requirements are to import the complete database with all the tables into a specified hive database using sqoop import. for example, I want to import mysql database 'hadoop_practice' along with all its tables to hive database 'hadoop_practice'. However, when I perform the following command

$ sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoop_practice --username root -P --hive-import

the tables are imported into the hive default database. I have tried logging into hive shell and changing the database but it still copies to the default database in hive. I know sqoop provides options of copying external database table into hive database table, but that will require me to copy a 1000 tables by giving separate commands for each import. I still couldn't find any option which allows me to import all the tables in one instance. I have thought about writing a script, but is there any way I can do it without writing the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the hive database using --hive-table options. so the command will be like

$ sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoop_practice --username root -P --hive-import --hive-table hadoop_practice.db

Comment: I tried this earlier but still the tables are being copied into the default database. I want to know if there is a workaround around this.

Answer (score 0):

You use the --hive-database option.

It was made available in Sqoop version 1.4.4: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-912

Comment: It doesn't work either. it is still going to default database

Answer (score 0):

$ sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoop_practice --username root -P --hive-import **--hive-database database_name** --create-hive-table