# Import table with sqoop with rename

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I'm very new with Hadoop & friends. I am looking at Cloudera tutorial example here: http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/developers/get-started-with-hadoop-tutorial/exercise-1.html that basically contains this command:

```
> sqoop import-all-tables \
    -m {{cluster_data.worker_node_hostname.length}} \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://{{cluster_data.manager_node_hostname}}:3306/retail_db \
    --username=retail_dba \
    --password=cloudera \
    --compression-codec=snappy \
    --as-parquetfile \
    --warehouse-dir=/user/hive/warehouse \
    --hive-import
```

This command failed in my case because there are already tables with the same names in my Hive warehouse. Can we rename the tables (or the underlying database name) while importing them to Hive? I can't seem to see that option.

Wirawan

Comment: This question is awfully similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955290/how-do-i-import-rdbms-data-to-a-specific-hive-database-using-sqoop-import

Comment: And, yes, the documentation is lagging. Welcome to the Hadoop ecosystem  :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can use --hive-table options to provide the custom name for the table.

```
sqoop-import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_dbname --username root --password cloudera --table orders1 --hive-import **--hive-table** test.oct8_2 --create-hive-table -m 1
```

You can see the directory structure in hdfs path:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/test.db
Found 3 items
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2019-10-07 19:20 /user/hive/warehouse/test.db/oct8
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2019-10-07 19:26 /user/hive/warehouse/test.db/oct8_2
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2018-12-06 03:16 /user/hive/warehouse/test.db/xmlcsv
```